# How do I update a table from an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$query = "SELECT users FROM tabl ORDER BY RAND()";
$result = mysql_query ($query)
    or die ("Query '$query' failed with error message: \"" . mysql_error () . '"');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $users[] = $row[0];
}

$current = end($users);
$partners = array();
foreach ($users as $user)
{
        $partners[$user] = $current;
        $current = $user;
}
print_r($partners);

$query2 = "UPDATE tabl SET partner = {$partners[0]} WHERE users = '$users'";
mysql_query ($query2)
    or die ("<br>Query '$query2' failed with error message: \"" . mysql_error () . '"');
```

That's the code I'm working with.  Everything is good until query2.  I've tried every variation I can think of, but nothing works.

The table on has two fields: users and partners. The code pulls the users in random order, then assigns them to eachother in a circle.  I need to populate the partners field with the assignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the update query inside the foreach loop, then you have the partner and user variables to hand without diving into the array later on:

```
foreach ($users as $user)
{
        $partners[$user] = $current;
        $current = $user;
        $query2 = "UPDATE tabl SET partner = '{$partners[$user]}' WHERE users = '{$user}'";
        mysql_query ($query2)
          or die ("<br>Query '$query2' failed with error message: \"" . mysql_error ()
}
```

Comment: It's a nice solution, but depending on how many $users there are, that may result in several queries on the database.

Comment: true, but if he's trying to assign a different partner to each user then you're not going to be able to avoid multiple queries...

Comment: This is a quick and easy fix, though I suspect the entire segment in the OP could be collapsed somewhat.

Comment: This solved it; except that you had one small error, its supposed to be: WHERE users = '$user'"    No {braces}.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome - The braces won't cause a problem, they sometimes help readability - you used them earlier in the query. Also I wasn't sure from the code whether user column type user was.

Answer (score 0):

Use `WHERE users IN ('.implode(',',$users).')'`

Answer (score 0):

I would change the code to:

```
$current = end($users);
$partners = array();
foreach ($users as $user)
{
    $partners[$user] = $current;
    $current = $user;
    $query2 = "UPDATE tabl SET partner = {$partners[$user]} WHERE users = '$user'";
    mysql_query ($query2)
        or die ("<br>Query '$query2' failed with error message: \"" . mysql_error () . '"');
}
print_r($partners);
```

But you could also do the following depending on the outcome you desire:

```
$userList = join(',', $users);
$query2 = "UPDATE tabl SET partner = {$partners[0]} WHERE users IN ($userList)";
mysql_query ($query2)
    or die ("<br>Query '$query2' failed with error message: \"" . mysql_error () . '"');
```

Comment: Your top solution was the same as Jon's but came later.  The bottom one didn't work out, but that's alright.

Comment: That's what happens when you are slow.  :)